# Access state variables defined with useState from callback function

Tags: reactjs, list, socket.io, callback, react-hooks

I have a comment section in my React app and I want to update it in real-time as other users comment. I use socket.io to listen to server sent events of new comments. When the app is notified about the new comment, I update the existing `comments` list with the new comment data.

However, when I'm trying to access `comments` state variable from the callback, it is always empty. How can I access `comments` from the callback so that I can append new data to the existing list of comments. Any help is highly appreciated.

```js
const Discussion = ({ lessonId,lessonName }) => {
    const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);

    const updateComments = (data) => {
      // this is always empty, even though it contains a list of objects and rendered as comments
      console.log(comments) 
      // This results in something like [data]. Existing objects have been disappeared.
      setComments([...comments,data])
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      Axios.get('/courses/lessons/' + lessonId + '/comments')
        .then(res => {
           console.log(res.data);
           setComments(res.data);

           socket.on('reply',data => {
             console.log(data)
           })
           // existing list of comments is updated with new data.
           socket.on('comment_'+lessonId,(data) => updateComments(data))
           })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            alert('An error occured');
        });
    }, [lessonId]);

    return <div></div>
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateComments` is called inside `useEffect` and the comments values it uses will be limited to the closure of `useEffect` and hence it will not have access to the updated comments value unless useEffect has a dependency on `comments`

An optimized solution here is to make use of functional state updater

```
const updateComments = (data) => {
  setComments(prevComments => [...prevComments,data])
}
```